# Design Data Model (Table Design) for variable attributes list

Tags: database, oracle, data-modeling, erd

I have requirements to create database ERD for the following problem:

The company now selling Cars with the following attributes:

```
CarId | Car brand | height | weight | passenger count
```

In the same time the company trading computers with the following attributes:

```
HardwareID | Ramsize | LCD | ScreensCount |
```

We need now to create new database a generic database per say to save these items and any new items the company will trade in future. Considering the following:

1. We don’t need to create two tables for each business or
2. We don’t need create one table and combine all of the attributes in one table. Because if we do that some of the fields will be null when we save computers all the cars fields will be null.
3. Basically the attributes list will vary per business.

I just need some ideas about how to create something like this.

Comment: What you're looking for is called an [entity-attribute-value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) and, as noted on that link ~ *"in many cases where data can be modelled in statically relational terms an EAV based approach is an **anti-pattern** which can lead to longer development times, poor use of database resources and more complex queries when compared to a relationally-modelled data schema"*

Comment: As @Phil states, this is the basic description of the EAV model, which will likely lead to more problems than it solves. If you really need something following this pattern, I'd suggest look into key-value NoSQL solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful,  I can start my own research from here. Thanks all.

Comment: By the way how to mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like cars and computers are both subtypes of the more generic term "products".  It sounds like the company is going to add more product types in the future, and those product types will have as yet unknown attributes.

EAV will let you do expand the list of attributes with no changes to data definitions, but it is usually an antipattern, as others suggest.  The problem is that undisciplined addition of attributes can result in synonyms in the attributes, that is one attribute with two or more names.  It can even result in homonyms in attributes, that is two or more attributes with the same name.  Once this happens, making use of the data is going to be as hard as making use of unmanaged data.

Two better design patterns might be as follows:  Class-table-inheritance ([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)) or Single-table-inheritance ([click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)).